# Doubt about real/complex differentials

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I know that
\begin{equation}
\partial_x f\,dx+\partial_yf\,dy=\partial_zf\,dz+\partial_{\bar z}f\,d\bar z,
\end{equation}
that we can also write as 
\begin{equation}
df=\partial f\,+\bar\partial f.
\end{equation} 
How can I prove that 
\begin{equation}
df=2\Re\{\partial f\}
\end{equation}
in case $f$ is real valued?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write out the definitions of $\partial f$, $f_z$, and $dz$
$$\partial f = f_{z} dz = \frac{1}{2} ( f_x - i f_y ) (dx + i dy) =
\frac{1}{2}( f_x dx + f_y dy + i (-f_y dx + f_x dy))$$
(do note that since $f$ is real valued, then $f_x$ and $f_y$ are real valued)